# When was the first appearance of the abbreviation RSA?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When was the first publication of the abbreviation RSA (Rivest, Sharmir, Adleman) because it does not appear in Martin Gardner’s article of 1977 which is at the following url:
https://simson.net/ref/1977/Gardner_RSA.pdf

Comment: Perhaps more suitable in https://hsm.stackexchange.com?

Comment: A terminus ante quem: My 1981 edition of  Knuth speaks of RSA

Comment: Not sure it is really the earliest, but Rivest himself used the acronym RSA in the paper "Critical remarks on ``Critical remarks on some public-key cryptosystems'' by T. Herlestam", dated from 1979 (only a year after the original paper).

Comment: Not a publication, but I found this : https://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/theses/kohnfelder-bs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

MathSciNet gives this paper:

> [MR0552072](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0552072)
>  
>   Blakley, Bob; Blakley, G. R.
>   [Security of number-theoretic public key cryptosystems against random attack. I](https://doi.org/10.1080/0161-117891853162). 
>   *Cryptologia* 2 (1978), no. 4, 306–321.

and also this one, which was received on April 6, 1978:

> [MR0557125](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0557125)
>  
>   Smith, Donald R.; Palmer, James T.
>  
>   [Universal fixed messages and the Rivest-Shamir-Adleman cryptosystem](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300009591). 
>  
>   *Mathematika* 26 (1979), no. 1, 44–52.

These papers are dated before the paper by Rivest mentioned in the comments, which was received on April 4, 1979:

> [MR0537789](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0537789)
>   Rivest, Ronald L.
>   [Critical remarks on: "Critical remarks on some public-key crypto systems" by T. Herlestam](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01930859).
>  
>   *BIT* 19 (1979), no. 2, 274–275.